# debugging a math code about point distance

Tags: python, debugging, math

I am working on a code(posted below). It is giving me an output of 0, but I cannot figure out where I went wrong or why it is giving me a zero instead. The actual output is sqrt(8) or ~2.8. I really appreciate the help.

```py
def point_distances(p1, p2):
    x1,y1=p1
    x2,y2=p2
    sqrt1=(x2-x1)^2
    sqrt2=(y2-y1)^2
    distance=math.sqrt(sqrt1+sqrt2)
    return distance
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that you are working with Python, however, you need to substitute the sqrt value associate with pow: `sqrt1=(x2-x1)^2` to `sqrt1 = math.pow(x2-x1,2)` or `sqrt1 = (x2-x1)**2`.

This symbol `^` is associated with XOR operation and not with power of a number.

Therefore, in this line `x1,y1=p1` you are associating the value of p1 to y1 only.

Comment: Thank you so much and yes it is python. I'm sorry, I should stated that in the question.